# Exception thrown by a function, where that function called when exception thrown in it

Tags: c#, function, exception

I have a function "ReturnString":

```
public static string ReturnString(string sa, string sb)
{
 try
 {
  ...
  ...
  return "xyz";
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  throw new clsException(ex.Message);
 }
}
```

it is call by more than 600 times from other more then 40 classes and win farms Mean's it has more than 600 references in more then 40 classes and win farms.

When Exception thrown by it, I want to know what is the it's last calling ref. when exception happen?
Please help me to solve this without changing function arguments.

Comment: If you really want to throw a new exception that at least include the original one as the inner exception. Then take a look at the stacktrace. For example `throw new clsException(ex.Message, ex);`

Comment: To what Peter said, do not throw a new exception, your variable ex should have all of the information in it to find out the calling method before the exception occurred.

Comment: You could put a logger in there, such as Log4Net or nLog

Comment: i want to know last calling ref. of the function, exception handling is not in this query

Comment: @FC3D If ex.StackTrace did not contain the information you need, then show us an example code which is calling that method and what exact information you want to get when there is an exception. Do not describe it, write down the exact information for that example.

Comment: e.StackTrace not work fo me but Orel code working and returning the last method name where it called any way thaks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize an instance of **StackTrace** class -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Then, get the first **StackFrame** -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe(v=vs.110).aspx

Finally, get the **MethodBase** of this frame; Its "Name" property is what you need -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase(v=vs.110).aspx

Try this:

```
    public static string ReturnString(string sa, string sb)
    {
        try
        {
            //...
            //...
            return "xyz";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StackTrace oStackTrace = new StackTrace();
            string sMethodName = oStackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
            //It's not a good practice to keep only the error message (you may need other exception details later)
            throw new clsException(string.Format("{0}: {1}", sMethodName, ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not ex.StackTrace ?

Comment: Because ex.StackTrace is just a string (you may be able to find the calling method name there, but even then, it may require some parsing. I have not tried it). StackTrace object on the other hand, keeps more information as well as the calling method name.

Comment: I expected that information to be in your answer ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo - I added some notes and references to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what is the it's last calling ref. when exception
>   happen?

Then check the exception **StackTrace**, that will let you know the entire call stack and the latest one responsible for exception. Also the `innerException` property if any.

Check the documentation on [Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It has a property `StackTrace` which you should check.

In your case, the exception object should have it `ex.StackTrace`

You may also want to get the `TargetSite` property value from your exception object saying `ex.TargetSite`

Comment: i want to know last calling ref. of the function, exception handling is not in this query

Comment: @FC3D, that's what I said ... you should check the stacktrace. if not, clarify what you mean by *last calling ref*

Comment: where i found stacktrace??

Comment: e..StackTrace not work fo me but Orel code working and returning the last method name where it called

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
throw new clsException(ex.Message);
```

As others have mentioned, `ex` already contains the info you want inside the `StackTrace` property (check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info).

But when you throw a new exception, you are only throwing the message, and ignoring all the info you want to get.

Just `throw` without a new exception, or include `ex` as the inner exception of your `clsException`.

Comment: unless the `clsException` is some custom exception which needs to be thrown on some specific occasion. Though am confused by OP's question

Comment: @Rahul yeah, that's what I think too, that's why I mentioned returning the original exception as the InnerException of his custom type. Nevertheless, doesn't seem as a good practice to me...